# angularjs manual bootstrapping does not update property value when input changes through method call

Tags: angularjs, bootstrapping, angularjs-ng-change

The problem, I have is AngularJS application is not updating the result when input changes in the input HTML field. If I turn this to auto bootstrapping it does work as expected. I do not know what am i doing wrong?

This is JS file.

```
angular.module('doublevalue', [])   
.controller('DoubleController', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.value = 0;
            $scope.double = function(value) { $scope.value = value * 2; }
               }]);

angular.element(document).ready(function() { 
             var div3 = document.getElementById('App3');
                angular.bootstrap(div3, ['doublevalue']);

     });
```

JSFIDDLE version:

[https://jsfiddle.net/as0nyre3/48/](https://jsfiddle.net/as0nyre3/39/)

HTML file:

```
<div id ='App3' ng-controller='DoubleController'>
                  Two controller equals
             <input ng-model='num' ng-change='double(num)'>
 <span> {{ value }}</span>  </div>
```

Auto bootstrapping one link:

https://jsfiddle.net/as0nyre3/40/

Please help me!

Comment: If it's copy/paste of your code then the `id ="App3"` has unnecessary space

Comment: It works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/as0nyre3/35/

Comment: will the space cause the problem? I fixed and tried but no luck

Comment: I did and changed it. Thank you and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working, with a problem like that you should always check your selectors

```
<div id="App3" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type='text' ng-model='name' ng-change='change()'>
  <br/> <span>changed {{counter}} times </span>
</div>
<script>
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('App3'), ['myApp']);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: yea! thanks but it does not if we send value from html and change depends on the value. check this one! https://jsfiddle.net/as0nyre3/42/

Comment: Obviously it will not work, you bootstrap an app ON INPUT but the controller containing logic is on parent element so the bootstraped app has no idea about it

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand! I am a newbie. please explain me clearly!

Comment: the document has a parent>child hierarchy i.e. `html>body>div#app3>input`, as you see `input` is at the bottom, so when you bootstrap the application on child element the application will be unaware of parent element that's why most of the applications are bootstraped on `html` or `body` elements

Comment: so is there anyways I can achieve this with bootstrapping manually?

Comment: Sure, bootstrap on the `div` element